# Unique identifier

Tags: c#

I want to generate a unique identifier in .NET with the following format:

xxxxx-xxxxx

where x is a number {0-9};

Comment: Please define the scope of "unique".

Comment: Smells like homework. Best practice to get help here is show what you have done in andvance. Go ahead, try it out the people here will get you out of trouble.

Comment: Alex, read this blog entry. It will scare you sh****ss: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx

Answer (score 17):

> I want to generate a unique identifier in .NET with the following format: xxxxx-xxxxx where x is a number {0-9}

Sure, no problem. We don't need to write a program for that. We'll just do it by hand.

00000-00000 is a unique identifier that has that format. Done.

Oh, you want more than one?  Well, you probably should have said that in the problem statement. :)

There are ten billion strings in that language and it is trivial to generate them all in order. So, generate 00000-00000 for your first unique identifier. Then 00000-00001 for your second unique identifier. Then 00000-00002 for your third unique identifier. And so on. You will be able to generate ten billion unique identifiers in this way; all you have to do is keep track of which one was the highest previously generated.

Comment: Dont be silly, use an auto increment, if you wsih to accomplish something as trivial as you state. This is not an answer. Infact its a joke.

Comment: This has a much higher chance of creating identical IDs between program runs. You'd have to make sure that all instances of the program running all over the world know what the most recent ID was. It is only a good answer in a very specific (and quite possibly imaginary) set of circumstances.

Comment: @David: Does it matter? The original poster hasn't said what the domain of uniqueness is. If it is "global" -- well, I just wrote and executed a program that generated all ten billion of them. So now the dream of total global uniqueness of generation is impossible, so we don't have to even consider it any more. :-) Since we don't have any clue what the actual problem is, it's hard to say what characterises a good solution.

Comment: "You will be able to generate one hundred million unique identifiers in this way" - should that say "ten billion"?

Comment: I completely agree with Eric. Eric has given the simplest solution on earth to this question. Why do we want assume the unique number generation is random, we can also assume number generation is serial.

Comment: Eric, curious_geek, If Eric's answer to this question is indeed the best answer, it means the question is seriously faulty, why use a weird string format to store increasing numbers. Why not just use a single ulong?

Using serial numbers is a great way to keep internal data separate over the course of a single run, but the way the question is phrased seems to imply that this is not what Alex is looking for.

Anyway, I've wasted more than enough time on a poorly phrased question and been punished for trying to answer it in the process.

Comment: Well put!  Whenever I hear a requirement for something "unique", my immediate thought is "sequence."  I'm baffled that so many people respond with "random" instead.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's not going to be anywhere near as unique as a real Guid, but you could just use Random to generate each digit. Be sure to use a private static Random object to avoid getting the same random sequence:

```
private static m_random as new System.Random();
public string MySpecialID()
{
  return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}-{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}",
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10),
       m_random.Next(0, 10));
}
```

Comment: Could you also generate two random numbers between 0 and 99999 and pad with zeros (using formatting)? I feel like there'd be a distribution difference but my brain doesn't function at 4 AM.

Comment: After 120,000 insertions, this algorithm has more than 50% chance of a collision.